# Differential equation of orthogonal curves

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, circles

Let us suppose we want to find the curve which is perpendicular to the curve $y=3x$. From the concept of straight lines,we know that the slope of that curve will be $-\frac{1}{3}$. Whose equation should be $y=-\frac{1}{3}x+c$.This can also be proved using differential equations. The derivative of 2nd curve will be $-\frac{1}{3}$. Hence, $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac {1}{3}$. By separation of variables we get $dy=-\frac{1}{3}dx$ and upon integration we get $y=-\frac{1}{3}x+c$. But let's see it from a different perspective.

The differential equation of first curve is $\frac{dy}{dx}=3=\frac{y}{x}$. Now,to get the orthogonal curve,we will have to replace $\frac{dy}{dx}$ by $-\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$. And so the differential equation of the 2nd curve is $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$. Again by variable separation we get,$ydy=-xdx$ which upon integration we get $\frac{y^2}{2}=-\frac{x^2}{2}+c$ which is $x^2+y^2=k$. Here we are getting straight line as the answer and again circle as the answer which is a contradiction. Although it is obvious and common sense that the straight line method is correct but I don't understand what's wrong with the circle method. It will be really helpful if I am pointed out where I made a fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation that defines your first curve cannot be uniquely defined as $\frac{y}{x}$; that is a property of all lines. The slope is simply $3$ everywhere: $\frac{dy}{dx}=3$. Thus, when you apply your method, you get all possible perpendicular lines. Since the first equation defines a radius of a circle centered at the origin, your perpendicular lines are tangents to the circle.

Comment: Thank you for answering,could you please explain from the line "Since the first equation defines a circle?" I didn't get it from there. I do not understand which equation is defining a circle here and how perpendicular lines are tangents to that circle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another question popped up in my mind. Suppose we have the line $y=3x$. Why should the family of straight lines be the only orthogonal trajectory of this line? Though it has been derived in the first step of my above post using differential equations,if we imagine a circle of any radius centered at origin,that family of circles also intersects the straight line $y=3x$ perpendicularly. So why do we exclude that case for our desired line $y=3x$?. Because if we form the particular differential equation just for this one line,we get $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1}{3}$ which doesn't give any circle.
.

Comment: $x^2+y^2=c$, differentiating wrt. x, we get $2x+\frac{dy}{dx}2y=0$, and thus $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$. I believe you're overthinking. If you have $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$ defines all lines (remember rise over run?). And if you apply the perpendicular rule, you get a circle. The tangents to the circle are the perpendicular lines to all lines intersecting the origin.